# card.io Android Phonegap Integration

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, card.io

I am trying to write a plugin for card.io and phonegap (crodova). My problem is when I click to open card.io to scan the credit card the app crashes with the following error:

**11-16 14:19:52.990: E/SurfaceTextureClient(17199): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -9**

11-16 14:19:55.580: A/libc(17199): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)

I am not pro in java but I followed the plugin documentation on phonegap and looked at some other ones already done.

Below is my code:

**Main Class**

```
package com.eliashajj.MyApp;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.elixir.vmart.R;

public class MyApp extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        try {
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Please make sure you have have and internet connection and try again.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

            TextView messageView = (TextView) dialog
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's my Card.IO handler**

```
package com.eliashajj.MyApp;

import io.card.payment.CardIOActivity;
import io.card.payment.CreditCard;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class Cardio extends Plugin{

    private static final String MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN = "MY APP TOKEN";
    private static final String SCAN = "scan";
    private static final String CC_VARIABLE = "cc_number";
    private static final String CC_MONTH_VARIABLE = "cc_month";
    private static final String CC_YEAR_VARIABLE = "cc_year";
    private static final String CC_CVV_VARIABLE = "cc_cvv";
    private static String CC_NUMBER;
    private static int EXPIRY_MONTH;
    private static int EXPIRY_YEAR;
    private static int CVV_NUMBER;


    public String callback;
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0ba7c0de;

    /*
     * Constructor
     */
    public Cardio(){

    }

    /*
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action        The action to execute.
     * @param args          JSONArry of arguments for the plugin.
     * @param callbackId    The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
     * @return              A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        this.callback=callbackId;

        //Context cc = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if(action.equals(SCAN)){
            scan();
        }
        PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        r.setKeepCallback(true);
        return r;
    }

    public void scan() {
        // This method is set up as an onClick handler in the layout xml
        // e.g. android:onClick="onScanPress"
        Context cc = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(cc, CardIOActivity.class);

        // required for authentication with card.io
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN);

        // customize these values to suit your needs.
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: true
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_ZIP, false); // default: false

        // hides the manual entry button
        // if set, developers should provide their own manual entry mechanism in the app
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); // default: false

        Log.d("SCANNING TAG: ", "1");
        // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((Plugin) this, scanIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        Log.d("SCANNING TAG: ", "2");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("SCANNING TAG: ", "3");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("SCANNING TAG: ", "4");

        Log.d("Request Code: ",""+requestCode);
        Log.d("Request Code 2: ",""+REQUEST_CODE);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.d("SCANNING TAG: ", "Data"+data);
            if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

                // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
                CC_NUMBER = scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber();
                // CC Expiry Month
                EXPIRY_MONTH = scanResult.expiryMonth;
                // CC Expiry Year
                EXPIRY_YEAR = scanResult.expiryYear;
                // CC CVV Number
                CVV_NUMBER = scanResult.cvv.length();

                try{
                    obj.put(CC_VARIABLE, CC_NUMBER);
                    obj.put(CC_MONTH_VARIABLE, EXPIRY_MONTH);
                    obj.put(CC_YEAR_VARIABLE, EXPIRY_YEAR);
                    obj.put(CC_CVV_VARIABLE, CVV_NUMBER);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){

                }
                this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj), this.callback);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Scanning was canceled
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(true);

    }
}
```

**Here's my Cordova plugin javascript**

```
var Cardio = function() {
};


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
Cardio.prototype.scan = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
        console.log("Cardio.scan failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("Cardio.scan failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return
    }

    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'Cardio', 'scan', []);
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.cardio) {
    window.plugins.cardio = new Cardio();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a lot of logs in the Java code, where do they show up in adb logcat?

Answer (score 0):

The libc SIGSEGV is a segfault from the native layer (libc). A couple of these did get fixed in the 3.0.2 release, so make sure you've got the latest version of the SDK.

Otherwise, it is hard to know exactly what the problem is without seeing the native crash dump. These are sometimes hidden in the DDMS logcat view since they are generated by Android rather than the hosting application, so you need to make sure you remove any logcat filtering to see it.